# Variables greater than 10 not valid

Tags: javascript

I'm very new at Javascript and trying to write a simple calculator with certain rules and boundaries. Below zero or above 17 and it gives "Out of range"; below zero works, >=17 doesn't.

If I set the upper boundary to a single digit, it works perfectly, but any double-digit number doesn't.

```
function math(){
    var age=parseFloat(AgeForm.age.value);
    var weight=(age+4)*2 ;
    if (age < 0 || age >= 17) {var weight="Out of range"};
    if (age >= 0 && age < 0.5) {var weight=3.5};
    if (age >= 0.5 && age < 1) {var weight=8};
    if (age > 9) {var weight=(age*3.3)};
    document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML = weight;
}
```

Comment: Use `else if` instead of just of just if for all but the first one. You'll also need to remove the empty statement (the semicolon) after your if blocks to do that.

Comment: It isn't working because the last condition is also matching (`age > 9`), so the value of `weight` is being overwritten again after you assigned `"Out of range"` to it.

Comment: @Paulpro -- of course, clear as day now that I look at it. I'll also change them all to else if to stack them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help